# Вызов конструктора в случае перегруженного оператора new

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Почему конструктор и деструктор вызываются дважды в этом коде?

```
#include <stdio.h>
class I
{
public:
    I()
    {
        printf("Constructor has been called for object %p\n",this);
    };
    I(int a)
    {
        v = a;
        printf("Constructor has been called for object %p\n",this);
        printf("Variable v has been assigned by value %d\n",a);
    }
    ~I()
    {
        printf("Destructor has been called for object %p\n",this);
    };
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        printf("Operator new has been called\n");
        I* o = ::new I;
        return (void*)o;
    }
    void operator delete(void *p)
    {
        printf("Operator delete has been called\n");
        ::delete (I*)p;
    }
private:
    int v;
};

int main()
{
    I* o = new I;
    delete o;
    return 0;
}
```

Первый раз конструктор вызывается в строке

```
I* o = ::new I;
```

Тут все понятно, конструктор вызывается при создании объекта операцией new.
Второй раз конструктор вызывается в этой строке

```
I* o = new I;
```

Почему так происходит, ведь тут это уже не операция new, а перегруженный мной оператор?
Программа выводит следующее

> Operator new has been called
>   Constructor has been called for object 0x238c010
>   Constructor has been called for object 0x238c010
>   Destructor has been called for object 0x238c010
>   Operator delete has been called
>   Destructor has been called for object 0x238c010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы путаете operator new и new-expression.

Для начала можете почитать мою писанину здесь:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1672116.html#post8812933

new-expression грубо говоря, работает в два этапа:

1. Вызов operator new для выделения *сырой памяти*.
2. Вызов конструктора для создания объекта.

А вот operator new выделяет сырую память (как malloc).
Никакие ***конструкторы operator new не вызывает***.

Исходя из этого смотрим Ваш код:

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    //...
    I* o = ::new I;//new-expression. Соответственно вызов operator new + конструктор
    //void* o = ::operator new(/*кол-во байт*/);//<--Вызов глобального operator new для выделения сырой памяти
    //...
}

//...
I* o = new I;//Здесь также new-expression, а значит также есть вызов конструктора.
```

То есть Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы в operator new пытаетесь использовать new-expression.
Тоже самое относится к delete-expression и operator delete - у Вас там та же ошибка.